# Occupy full width - facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas, frame

I have a facebook application that needs exactly 1280 pixels of width to display correctly.
Right now I'm using facebook's fluid canvas but my problem is this frame which occupies about
270 pixels of screen with:

[image: img1]

Better quality image:  http://postimage.org/image/no8732ckh/full/

Can I disable/remove this frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a facebook application that needs exactly 1280 pixels of width to display correctly.

Tough luck :-P

Only possible solution: “Get out” of Facebook, and have your app run on your own website, so that you can use the full browser screen width the user has available.

Or, of course: Make your app less space-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't. without this frame facebook can't generate revenue anymore and then they aren't interested in your app.

Comment: and there is no way to alter its width either?

Comment: i don't think so because it does not belong to your app